# Cannot Find Reference To TableAdapter c#

Tags: c#, tableadapter, strongly-typed-dataset, visual-studio-2015

I've added a DataSource to my Solution, which has generated a DataSet and TableAdapters. I cannot reference these table adapters from my main form.

Example:

```
        try
        {
            user_count = (int)this.UsersTableAdapter.count_users();

        } catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
```

Error:

Main does not contain definition for UsersTableAdapter

I've found the definitions for these adapters in DataSet.Designer.cs
How do I import or reference these definitions for use within my Main.cs?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to declare and instantiate my dataset and tableadapters in my Main.Designer.cs file in order for them to be accessible in my Main.cs Form.